# LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano

I'm following [this guide](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/deploy-rails-apps-with-capistrano) to deploy my Rails app on DigitalOcean using Capistrano.

At the end of stop 5 I check the server availability through the following command:

```
cap production deploy:check
```

Which results in:

```
alucardu@alucardu-VirtualBox:~/sites/movieseat$ cap production deploy:check
cap aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/rbenv
/home/alucardu/sites/movieseat/Capfile:18:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

In my gemfile I have:

```
# Add capistrano
gem 'capistrano-bundler' # for capistrano/bundler
gem 'capistrano-rails' # for capistrano/rails/*
```

And:

```
group: :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.0', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', github: 'capistrano/rbenv', require: false
end
```

In my Capfile I have:

```
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```

I also did a rbenv version check.

```
alucardu@alucardu-VirtualBox:~/sites/movieseat$ rbenv -v
rbenv 0.4.0-98-g13a474c
```

Can someone point me to the problem?

**UPDATE**

I guess I hadn't installed the gem yet.

Fixed it.

```
gem install capistrano-rbenv
```

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this by running `bundle exec cap production deploy` instead of `cap production deploy`.

Answer (score 2):

Capistrano's tasks usually run in `production` environment. So in your `Gemfile` add gems related to capistrano in `production` group

```
group :development, :production do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.0', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', github: 'capistrano/rbenv', require: false
end
```

Comment: The ':' after group is wrong. The correct syntax would be `group :development, :production do`